# Как перевести .js файл в .exe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

У меня есть файл index.js
Его нужно перевести в .exe-файл.
Читал про jsc, но так и не понял, как им пользоваться.
Можно ли это сделать так же, как и в Python с помощью pyinstaller?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8173232/7485582

Comment: @КириллМалышев даже можно дать более конкретную ссылку на ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/33364620/4496422 именно эти инструменты я бы использовал